# programmatic (or tool) way to encrypt PDF file in outlook

Tags: .net, email, vba, encryption, outlook

i am using a document management system to export pdf files directly into a new outlook message.

since at this point the pdf files are not encrypted i need to encrypt them. is there any programmatic way of doing this? or perhaps such a tool exists ?

Comment: What about encrypting the entire email with PGP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PDFcreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) can be used to "print" PDF files with encryption.